# WP_list_table add custom row action

Tags: wp-list-table

I have been following the following guide: [step by step guide to wp list table](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) however i can't figure out where should i define my action: duplicate in the code. I want to add a link to simply duplicate the according row, any idea ?

```
$actions = array(
    'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=cruises_form&id=%s">%s</a>', $item['id'], __('Edit', 'cruise_list_manager')),
    'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Delete', 'cruise_list_manager')),
    'duplicate' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=duplicate&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Duplicate', 'cruise_list_manager')),
);

return sprintf('%s %s',
    $item['name'],
    $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, the action needs to be defined in your plugin function:

```
function process_bulk_action()
    {
```